# Karaf - getting "Unable to load class" when installing feature

Tags: jackson, apache-camel, cxf, apache-karaf

I am new to cxf and camel and I am running into some issues when trying to use JacksonJsonProvider.

I am trying to define a cxf service endpoint which consumes a json object and sends the request to a camel route. The camel route is not important for my issue.

In my blueprint.xml file I have defined a bean for JacksonJsonProvider:

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
```

When I try to install my feature in karaf I receive the following error:

> BlueprintContainerImpl           | ?
>   ? | 21 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.2 | Unable to start
>   blueprint container for bundle test-mgw-api
>   org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException:
>   Unable to load class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
>   from recipe BeanRecipe[name='jsonProvider']

I have already added the correct dependency to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

There must be something simple I am missing here, but I have spend many hours to figure it out now and I am getting nowhere.
**Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?**

I have provided my code below here.

**Service interface:**

```
@Path("/auth/")
public interface AuthService {

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response login(LoginRequest loginRequest);

    @GET
    @Path("/person/get/{id}/")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    Response getPerson(@PathParam("id") String id);

    @DELETE
    @Path("/person/delete/{id}")
    void deletePerson(@PathParam("id") String id);
}
```

**Request model:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Login")
public class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int loginType;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.loginType = 1;
    }

    public LoginRequest() {
    }
}
```

**Blueprint.xml**

```
<blueprint
        xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
        xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
        xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

        <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="test.mgw.cxf.receive" update-strategy="reload">
            <cm:default-properties>
                <cm:property name="CXFserver" value="http://localhost:8989/"/>
                <cm:property name="service" value="rest" />
            </cm:default-properties>
        </cm:property-placeholder>

        <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>

    <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="${CXFserver}${service}"
                  serviceClass="test.mgw.api.AuthService"
                  loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20">
        <cxf:providers>
            <ref component-id="jsonProvider"/>
        </cxf:providers>
    </cxf:rsServer>
</blueprint>
```

Comment: Did you declare camel-cxf dependencies in your `pom.xml`? I am not sure it is 100% necessary but in our environment it is needed to bridge the Jackson Jax-RS  with Camel.

Comment: Did you install the jackson dependency in Karaf as well? And not just your bundle.

Comment: @ruffp I do also have 
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        </dependency>`
in my pom.xml

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti I tried installing osgi bundles in karaf using
`install mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13`
`install mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.13`
`install mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13`
I also started the bundles, but it still does not work. I get the same error.

Comment: @Ringbo and the feature `camel-cxf` is also deployed in the OSGI as 'Souciance' said? I notice we also have a feature `camel-jackson` in our environment.

Comment: Yes as @ruffp mentions, have you installed all the related Camel dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You should change in the blueprint the tag to [jaxrs like this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-JSONsupport):

```
<jaxrs:server id="endpoint1">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```